# ModX: Custom query only works when I update the snippet

Tags: php, mysql, code-snippets, modx, modx-evolution

I have a script that runs a PHP MySQL query with information gathered via a form. The query works fine but the weird thing is that it wont update the search variables if someone refreshes and enters new input into the form.

I can actually see the correct variables in the URL but they are just not being repeated in the query.

The really odd thing is if I go and edit the snippet in the ModX back end - even if its just adding a comment - save it and refresh the page it works until I try a new search again.

Would anyone know whats happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your form snippet cached? You'll need it uncached to have it run fresh every time:

```
[[!snippet]]
```

That goes for any placeholders too:

```
[[!+placeholder]]
```

Comment: Thanks! thats probably the issue. But I made the change and now the snippet doesnt run at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah no its cool - I had it round the wrong way - with Evo it looks like: [!snippet!]

Comment: Ooops I assumed it was Revo, missed that tag. In Evo you can't use `!` in placeholders so just use `[!snippet!]` and `[+placeholder+]`